# Replace the last match in a string

Tags: ruby

I'm playing around with Ruby to do some file versioning for me. I have a string `2.0.0.65` . I split it up, increment the build number (65 --> 66) then I want to replace the 65 with the 66.  In this replace though, I only want to replace the last match of the string. What's the best way in Ruby to do this?

```
 version_text = IO.read('C:\\Properties')
 puts version_text
 version = version_text.match(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/)[1]
 puts version
 build_version = version.split('.')[3]
 puts build_version
 incremented_version =  build_version.to_i + 1
 puts incremented_version`
 ...
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to increment the integer at the very end of a string then try this:

```ruby
s = '2.0.0.65'
s.sub(/\d+\Z/) {|x| x.to_i + 1} # => '2.0.0.66'
```

Comment: Note that this is not the last integer in any string (e.g. "43 cats"), but rather a string that ends with an integer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
parts = "2.0.0.65".split('.')
parts[3] = parts[3].to_i + 1
puts parts.join(".")
```

output:

```
2.0.0.66
```

This gives you more control over just using a string replacement method, as now you can increment other parts of the version string if needed more easily.

Comment: Or, if the number of parts can change, replace `parts[3]` with `parts[-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = '2.0.0.65'

def incr_version(version)
  parts = version.split('.')
  parts[-1] = parts[-1].to_i + 1
  parts.join('.')
end

incr_version(sample) # => '2.0.0.66'
```

Comment: You would need parts[-1] = parts[-1].to_i + 1 , right? EDIT: removed to_s, it works without it.

Comment: @Bwalks Indeed. I had it right my fiddling in irb and miss transcribed into the answer.  Edited to correct.  As you noticed, join invokes #to_s on each element.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the string with the build number, you only need to use 'succ' method

```
'2.0.0.65'.succ()
```

Which gives you the string

```
'2.0.0.66'
```

Comment: Cool idea but `'2.0.0.99'.succ # => '2.0.1.00'` which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, you're right ;) It depends on what he wants to do. Maybe if he reaches the version 99 its time to reconsider his versioning :D or maybe he wants to add some more logic to the code. In any case he has the last word :)

Answer (score 1):

For fun, if you want to increment the last integer in any string you could do this:

```
str = "I have 3 cats and 41 rabbits"
str.reverse.sub(/\d+/){ |s| (s.reverse.to_i+1).to_s.reverse }.reverse
#=> "I have 3 cats and 42 rabbits"
```

This is only valid when you modify your regex to match the reversed version of the text.

More generally, you can do this:

```
class String
  # Replace the last occurrence of a regex in a string.
  # As with `sub` you may specify matches in the replacement string,
  # or pass a block instead of the replacement string.
  # Unlike `sub` the captured sub-expressions will be passed as
  # additional parameters to your block.
  def rsub!(pattern,replacement=nil)
    if n=rindex(pattern)
      found=match(pattern,n)
      self[n,found[0].length] = if replacement
        replacement.gsub(/\\\d+/){ |s| found[s[1..-1].to_i] || s }
      else
        yield(*found).to_s
      end
    end
  end
  def rsub(pattern,replacement=nil,&block)
    dup.tap{ |s| s.rsub!(pattern,replacement,&block) }
  end
end

str = "I have 3 cats and 41 rabbits"

puts str.rsub(/(?<=\D)(\d+)/,'xx')
#=> I have 3 cats and xx rabbits

puts str.rsub(/(?<=\D)(\d+)/,'-\1-')
#=> I have 3 cats and -41- rabbits

puts str.rsub(/(?<=\D)(\d+)/){ |n| n.to_i+1 }
#=> I have 3 cats and 42 rabbits
```

Note that (as with `rindex`) because the regex search starts from the end of the string you may need to make a slightly more complex regex to force your match to be greedy.

Comment: That's a lot of work for `"I have 2 cats with 4 legs".sub(/\d+(?=[^\d]*\Z)/) { |m| m.to_i + 1 }` # => "I have 2 cats with 5 legs"

Comment: Heh, I was _just_ thinking of that solution, though I'd write it as `.sub(/\d+(?=\D*\Z)/)`. But, there are some times where writing the negative-to-the-end is going to be prohibitively hard.